# Targeting .net 3.5 with C# 6 in monodevelop

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to build a mono project targeting 3.5 that also uses CS6 code. I'm on Debian (sid) using monodevelop. I know that "Once upon a time" I was able to build this on Debian with monodevelop, so something's probably misconfigured.

I have [a parallel mono](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tpokorra:/mono-3.12/Debian_8.0/amd64/) installed in `/opt` and while I can add it to my .net runtimes list the projects in the solution still complain that 3.5 isn't installed.

I can't just downgrade my entire mono installation because the CS6 features only start working in the same mono version that drops support for 3.5 (Wonderful)

How can I build this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently debian's `mono-devel` doesn't include < 4.0 support out of the box. I still don't know which package it was mysteriously missing because it was eaiser to just install from the Xamarin repo directly.

While installing mono from Xamarin directly should have fixed it, the debian versions were higher so even explicitly specifying a higher version wasn't enough.

In the end I have this source line:

```
deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main
```

And this pin:

```
Package: *mono*
Pin: release o=Xamarin
Pin-Priority: 901
```